# How to import ruby RSpec data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec

Can someone please show how to directly import ruby RSpec data . I haven't found a single answer to this after hours of research.

I'm trying to return "fruit" and "vegetable" to the **method foods** in the pull.rb file. That data would come from the data.rb

**data.rb**

```js
let(:food_data) {
  JSON.parse('[
{
  "Plant": "Fruit",
  "Type": "Apple"
},
{
  "Plant": "Vegetable",
  "Type": "Carrot"

},
{
  "Plant": "Fruit",
  "Type": "Orange"
},
{
  "Plant": "Vegetable",
  "Type": "Spinach"
}

]')
}
```

**pull.rb**

```js
def foods
File.open('data.rb'))
    [:food_data][0]
    [:food_data][1]
end
```

Comment: It’s hard to say how to accomplish what you wanted because literally all the code is wrong and the intent is absolutely unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the data into a plain json file:

**food_data.json**

```
[
{
  "Plant": "Fruit",
  "Type": "Apple"
},
{
  "Plant": "Vegetable",
  "Type": "Carrot"

},
{
  "Plant": "Fruit",
  "Type": "Orange"
},
{
  "Plant": "Vegetable",
  "Type": "Spinach"
}

]
```

then load it from ruby:

```
require 'json'
def foods
  JSON.parse(File.read("food_data.json")).first(2).map do |food|
    food["Plant"]
  end
end

foods # => ["Fruit", "Vegetable"]
```